# Token has been expired or revoked Again and Again in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, email, google-cloud-platform, gmail, google-workspace

The “WP Mail SMTP” revoked the connection from my G-mail account again and again.
No password changed.I missed my order notification again and again.Please tell me why it is happening.

WordPress Version:- 5.6
PHP Version:-
WP Mail SMTP Version:- 2.6.0
Web Server:- Apache
PHP version:- 7.3.5
License key type:- lite

Comment: Hello please search a bit more on google before asking https://wordpress.org/support/topic/token-has-been-expired-or-revoked-2/

Comment: That topic does not solve the problem for me. Password has not changed, but token was expired anyway

Answer (score 0):

To solve it I accessed WP Mail SMTP settings on WP Admin Dashboard and, in the Authorization, pressed "Removed the Connection"

[image]

And then allowed the connection again ("Allow plugin to send emails using your Google account")
[image]

And that redirected to the following screen (after login), and had to allow

[image]

Note: One needs to be in the Google Account that one configured the API ([see here how to configure WP Mail SMTP for Google Workspace/Gmail Mailer](https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-gmail-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/))

---

Token has been expired or revoked, but it is hard to know exactly what is the problem.

My guess is that it could be happening for a variety of reasons, such as resetting the password of the account one is using.

A WPMail SMTP creator wrote ([here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/token-has-been-expired-or-revoked-8/#post-14377900)) the following:

> Hi everyone,
>
> it looks like this is happening to more and more users, but we don’t
> know what the reason behind this account disconnect is. We have a lot
> of testing sites set up, and we never experienced this issue. I just
> rechecked my testing sites.
>
> One of the main things that could cause this issue is if your
> Google/Gmail API app is in “Testing” mode. Could you please check if
> the google API project is in the “Production” mode by going to the
> Google API console, opening the project for our plugin integration,
> then go to “OAuth Consent Screen” and check the “Publishing status”.
> More info can be found in this screenshot. It should say “In
> production”.
>
> If that’s not the reason, then we have to go over all the Gmail API
> project options together and see what the differences are. I think it
> has to be something on Google’s side since they are the ones that
> invalidate the token, not us.
>
> And to answer bst7’s questions: The Google API app is created by you,
> to be used just by you, even though on the free Gmail accounts you
> have the app set to “External use” (no other option is available), but
> nobody else will use this app apart from you, since you are the only
> one that knows the project credentials and have logged into it from
> your secured WP admin dashboard.
>
> Our plugin requires top-level permission because that’s the best way
> to future-proof our plugin development. If we were to improve our
> plugin and would have required only the minimal permission level, upon
> the plugin update, your connection would be invalidated and the newly
> added plugin functionality would not work. For example, we added the
> support for aliases a few versions ago and if we didn’t have the
> top-level permission, after the update all users would have to reset
> the connection manually in order for the Gmail mailer to work properly
> again. It’s just a way to make sure we can keep improving our plugin
> without any issues for our users.

However, in my case the Publishing status is "In production" and the problem also happened.

[image]